# node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83

Tags: node.js, module, sails.js, bcrypt

i got this issue.. someone have a idea.. whats that mean.? would like to start my app on my local machine. but dosent work wight way. I'm stucking here with modules or note and bcrypt ? are someone have a idea to slove this issue and why this show up.?

```
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:www cyberspace$ sails lift

info: Starting app...

/Users/cyberspace/Desktop/www/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
              ^
Error: dlopen(/Users/cyberspace/Desktop/www/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/cyberspace/Desktop/www/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at bindings (/Users/cyberspace/Desktop/www/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object. (/Users/cyberspace/Desktop/www/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object. (/Users/cyberspace/Desktop/www/config/passport.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:www cyberspace$
```

this is the commandline tool in my terminal on mac os. - I'm happy when some have a tip or this way to slove and fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

`0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03` indicates a Linux shared library.

You need to re-install your dependencies (`npm install`) (you may remove your `node_modules` completely first just to be extra sure no remnants are left) on your local machine so that `bcrypt` gets compiled for the right platform.